# Transpose multi-column data frame by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,2), ID=rep(1:2,each=3),  
                 year=rep(2012,6),tmin=c(1:6),tmax=c(7:12))
```

And I want to have a data frame like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:2,each=2), weather=rep(c("tmin","tmax"),2),
                  year=rep(2012,4), m1=c(1,7,4,10), m2=c(2,8,5,11),
                  m3=c(3,9,6,12))
```

In real data there are thousands data for 12 months, but basically I hope to transpose the data frame by column of month, I've tried using t and aggregate, and also searched around, but with no success, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, **reshape2** would be my first thought:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df,id.vars = 1:3),ID + variable + year ~ month,fun.aggregate = sum,value.var = "value")
  ID variable year  1  2  3
1  1     tmin 2012  1  2  3
2  1     tmax 2012  7  8  9
3  2     tmin 2012  4  5  6
4  2     tmax 2012 10 11 12
```

Only thing left is to rename the columns, if you like.